# Understand evaluation and loop

Tags: matlab

Trying to understand this code :

```
A = [1 2 3]

T = A(:,1:end);

fprintf('\nvalues ', T);
```

A creates a Matrix of dimension 1 x 3

When I run this code, this is printed :

```
A =

     1     2     3
```

Why is T not implicitly evaluated and printed to screen ?

I'm unfamiliar with this syntax : `A(:,1:end);` is this selecting the first column of Matrix and looping ?

Comment: A line of code without a semicolon echoes the result of that line to the Command Window.  It does not change how that line is evaluated.  Semicolons are used so you don't unnecessarily see output in the Command Window as you create MATLAB expressions.  Also, `T = A(:,1:end);` is rather superfluous... it says to access matrix `A` in such a way where you are accessing all of the rows (1st dimension: `:`) and getting all of the columns from the first column to the end (2nd dimension: `1:end`).  You might as well just say `T = A;` because you're essentially copying the entire matrix over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines of code that are evaluated in screen "implicitly" are the ones that do not end with `;`. The semicolon operator **suppresses** the printing of the result of that line.

In your code,

```
A = [1 2 3]   % No semicolon -> print

T = A(:,1:end); % semicolon -> no print
```

---

The `end` keyword has nothing to do with the printing. Its a keyword very useful to do vetorized operations in Matlab.

Saying `A(:,1:end)` you are telling MATLAB " take *all the values* (`:`) from column indexes starting on `1` until the last column of the matrix `end`. Basically, in this case, all the values of `A`. You can try `A(1:end,1:end)` and check that returns the same thing.

For a more useful example, you might want all the matrix *but* the first row, then you would use `A(2:end,:)`.